# Disable MailChimp Signup Forms

Tags: mailchimp

I am using MailChimp for my newsletter. I do not want that people can sign up for my newsletter. How can I disable the mail Signup Forms? [image]

If I click on **General forms** I find a public link where people can register for my newsletter. I do not want that such a link exists. How can I disable it?

*Explanation*: I have a membership site and I send a newsletter to those members with MailChimp. I synchronize the email accounts from MailChimp with the database of my membership site through https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/ and webhooks. I only want that people from the membership site are included in the newsletter.

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe that when you sync your list with the api it makes your list an exact copy of what you send over, so even if someone found a way to sign up they would be removed the next time the sync occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it. However, there is a work-around for making sure you only send to people on your membership site.

1. You will need to [create a hidden group in Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/help/getting-started-with-groups/)

It needs to be a hidden group and it might be called "Members". Make sure that people are **not** added to this group by default. Then you add/synch all your legitimate members to this Members group and only send emails to this group.

Every now and then you could check to see if there are any stray people on the list who somehow got there but are not on the group - they may have tried to sign up from the form by themselves... upon which you can remove them from the list as needless clutter or pitch them a sale.

2. Secondly, you will need to [adjust your publicity settings](https://mailchimp.com/help/about-list-publicity/) to private so that your campaigns are not available to the public.

Answer (score 0):

You can create (or update) a field in the signup form to be Required and Hidden. The viewer of the form will not be able to submit a record since they will not see the Hidden field that must be filled in.

The caveat in doing the is when you are manually adding a contact through your account. You will need to provide a value in that field, but the field will not be hidden from you.